# jquery show/hide toggle broken in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have created a page with multiple divs which I want to toggle into the same place. This works fine in chrome and firefox but as expected not in internet explorer. I have used the same method on one page and it works fine but when i duplicate it on another page to work with more then one div then it breaks.

The jquery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

//Hide the box       
  $("#sub1").hide();


//Sets up the click function and speed  
  $("#btn-slide").click(function(){
  $("#sub1").slideToggle("slow",function(){



//Toggles link text between open and close  
//=="Open" or as changed here to "VIEW DR. MARTENS HISTORY" is vital in order to close the box
($("#btn-slide").html()=="| THE PUNK SCENE |")?$("#btn-slide").html("Close"):$("#btn-slide").html("| THE PUNK SCENE |");



  });
  return false; 
}); 
</script>
```

This is in my head tag and I have duplicated 3 times so have it working on 4 divs in total. I have changed the #btn-slide to #btn-slide1 etc.

The html is:

```
<div id="move"><a  href="#" title="| THE PUNK SCENE |" id="btn-slide"  >| THE PUNK SCENE |</a></div>
```

This is the link to click to open the hidden div. Again I have more of these divs with different div id's calling the different #btn-slide.

This is the html for the div that is being opened:

```
  <div id="sub1"><strong>The Punk scene</strong> -and 2nd Generation Skins<br />
    <br />
    Following the Skins the Punk scene was a well  known youth subculture to wear Dr. Martens. When Punk became known in the late  70's a second generation of Skins derived from the Punk scene. The media have  often portrayed the 2nd gen Skin over the years, with the popular opinion of  Skinhead culture being a 14 hole Dr. Marten (and white laces wearing)  aggressive young white male. Fascist parties sourced new recruits from football  games and amongst a violent throng of spectators some new recruits were Skins.  <br />
       </div>
```

I hope this makes sense anyone got any thoughts on how to get it IE compatible. I have used the f12 tools when on IE but there are no errors.

Comment: "This is in my head tag and I have duplicated 3 times so have it working on 4 divs in total". Yuck. Just give all the divs a common classname and then apply the behavior to the class, not to each element by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing some closing brackets.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/esRFt/7/

It seems to work fine with IE8.  What version does it have issues with?

Comment: I have IE 9 which it doesn't seem to be able to open and close properly :)

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle link and it turned out the to be the: | keyboard dashed I had used- "| THE PUNK SCENE |".
Thanks for taking a look and mentioning the jsfiddle link, I thought it would be something little like that... :-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `html()` function just calls `.innerHTML` internally, which is known to be buggy in IE. You should use a different test (such as `hasClass()`) in your ternary condition.